# Site Architecture and content management

Tags: nodes

The problem (more my lack of knowledge) is finding a way to display the content I have in an easy to manage/update manner. The site is comprised of mostly pages of links (they currently pull from a database onto pages in a very simple java setup with template files) and I would like to transfer those to drupal and use content types and possibly views (open to any suggestion) to display the links.

The main and secondary links are to be displayed in the main navigation - secondary links in a drop down - with both the main links and secondary links having pages. click on a main link and it will display all of the secondary links. On the secondary link pages are links categorized under it, so it is basically a three tier navigation.

Because the links are used both in the navigation and page content it would be amazing if someone could enlighten me on a way to enter these in Drupal once rather than multiple places to accomplish my goal and keep the content neat on the backend.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a good answer for this queston (but I may be wrong - I usually am). You're looking for a tutorial on content management with Drupal, and we don't do tutorials here. If you don't get an answer, you could Google for a tutorial or even buy a book (there are plenty). Or you could try to move your present content to your experimental Drupal site (too bad that useful snippet of info was deleted from your question). Come back here with a much more focused question when you get stuck. We answer questions here (in particular well-defined ones), but we're not keen on tutorials.

Comment: I have had no luck with tutorials covering what I would like to accomplish so I thought it would be a good idea to ask here for ideas.

If this were just pages of content I would be good to go but it is rather a different beast to tame using views and taxonomies I'm not quite comfortable with. Thought maybe a seasoned Drupal user could give me a few pointers.